# How can you determine remaining space on page with ezpdf?

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, ezpdf

I'm using rospdf/php-pdf - the middle of the pdf is a table of variable length.  I want to make sure there is enough space to print the final section on the page, if  not I want to add a new page.  I'd like to do something like this but $position has no value.  How can I find out the current position?

```
$position = $pdf->ezSetDy;

if($position < 100){
    $pdf->ezNewPage();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
$yPos = $pdf->y - $pdf->ez['bottomMargin'];
if ($yPos < 100) {
    $pdf->ezNewPage();
}
```